# Add ASP.NET MVC Area to ASP.NET Web Forms existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website developed in ASP.NET Web Forms with .NET FrameWork 4.5.1

We have a requirement to build a replica of the site for mobile devices (responsive doesn't work for us in this case) so I ended up thinking of doind this part of the site with ASP.NET MVC.

**Note before you continue:**
*I know there are a few questions answered about this topic and in the web there are some articles on how to mix them. But none of them works for me because I'm trying to use the One ASP.NET Framework to avoid going through a lot of manual work.*

So, what I did was:

1. Add the Nuget Package for MVC in my ASP.NET WebForms project
2. Once added, I configured an MVC Area to contain my Mobile site in MVC

The project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

And here comes my problem: If I run any of the ASPX pages, they run ok. When I go to the /Mobile/Home/Index it says the resource is not found. I suspect this is because the App_Start folder doesn't exists in my project and Starup.cs isn't there either so the website doesn't know anything about MVC routing.

**Question**

1. How can I add the App_Start folder and the Starup.cs with defaults values without suffering the process (avoiding copy/paste or manual processes)?
2. How can I make this both (web type projects) live together as they say it can be done with the One ASP.NET Framework?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to register the areas in your Global.asax (add it through the Add Item menu option if it does not exist):

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    }

}
```

This will enable the link to your Mobile @ `localhost/{ProjectName}/Mobile/Home`

Comment: So, no need to create the Starup.cs? If I need the BundleConfig.cs I have to create it myself too?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a static configuration file for each functional aspect of MVC you would like to use in the subproject.

Comment: @FelipeCorrea I just ran a test with an empty asp project, and all you need is the area registration in the Global.asax, which you add add to the main project if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I guess the other files are only required if one needs them to specify more routes or bundles. Awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

**If I was going to mix the two within the same project, I'd start with an MVC project**, and have the ASP.Net pages be within their own subfolder.

**But perhaps you should consider having 2 separate projects, one per "application".**

So now a separate application might be deployed to MainApplicationFolder\SomeSubfolder.

Of course, you might also then want to consider something like the following for your links then:

```
@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/SomeController/SomeAction")
```

Comment: I get your point, though I think it is good to take advantage of the capabilities of the framework. If you can use them together and it applies to the problem you are trying to solve, why over complicate it separating styles, javascript references and deployments? They say (Microsoft) that the One ASP.NET Framework allows you to start with any of the technologies and later on integrate whichever you want: Web API, MVC and Web Forms. I want to make it using this capabilities.